Do the electric fields from changing $B$ fields effectuate beyond electrical shield barriers?

As depicted, there exists a changing $B$ toroidal solenoid field, which encloses a copper torus. Maxwells third law tells us, that this will result in an electrical field.
$$
\nabla \times E = -\frac{d}{dt}B
$$
Given that copper is an electric shield, will the copper shell block $E$ from existing? Or does enclosing a electrically shielded volume in a changing $B$ field incite an electrical field within that electrically shielded volume?
Unless I'm mistaken, the electrical field has no apparent source location, from which its curl begins around a fluctuating B field vector. Thus, would it begin in every location of its curl, and the only places it wouldn't exist would be within the shell. However, that $E$ field would begin within the enclosed volume as well as outside of it.
